# C++ Regex not matching multiline strings

Tags: c++, regex

I am having problems with C++0x regex when the string Im matching is a multiline string.
Here is the code snippet Im trying to use:

```
std::smatch regMatch;
std::string data = "<key>id</key><string>1</string>\n<key>user</key><string>admin</string>";
if (std::regex_match(data, regMatch, std::regex("<key>user</key><string>(.*?)</string>"))) {
    std::cout << "Reg match: " << regMatch[1].str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the expected results are, and why the current code isn't matching your expectations? There is not multiline support in MSVC10. What are you using to compile?

Comment: The expected output is: something like "Reg match: admin" for this snippet. And yes, I am using MSVC10 to compile. Any solution?

Comment: It stopped being called C++0x a few years ago

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `regex_search` instead of `regex_match`.

By the way, why not use `(.*)` instead of `(.*?)`?

Comment: Yep, looks like `regex_match` is the real problem here.  The fact that the target string is multiline is irrelevant as long as the line separators are *between* entries and not inside them.

Answer (score 3):

The dot `.` does not match newline characters by default.  You can add the switch `(?s)` to the beginning of the regex to switch on newline matching for the dot:

```
(?s)<key>user</key><string>(.*?)</string>
```

However, I'm not a huge fan of this because not all languages support this in their regex engines.  Additionally, there might be another part of your regex pattern involving a dot that you *don't* want to match newlines.  My preferred method is to just use a character set that includes a character class such as \s or \w along with its negated class.  It's a pretty straightforward way of telling the regex to match this will match absolutely everything:

```
<key>user</key><string>([\w\W]*?)</string>
```

Maybe I'm misinterpreting how your XML is going to be parsed, but I've got to say that it's a bit odd how you intend to capture a string with the key name "user" that may or may not contain newlines (and other whitespace characters, and all other characters).  Are you really okay with a user named

`admin$#*
   &%                                                   '";
               _____`?

Comment: Don't bother - that throws `std::regex_error(error_syntax)` (in [gcc](http://rextester.com/WND29854), [clang](http://rextester.com/DTYYU20933) and [msvc](http://rextester.com/BFBYLO75079)). There is also no reference to this syntax in `std::regex` documentation.

Comment: The (?s) approach throws an exception with the GNU libc++, however the "preferred method" quoted of replacing (.*) with ([\s\S]*) does work, i.e. matches subsequent multilines rather than halting at linefeed.